# PrimeFaces DatePicker: showIcon blocks tabulation if component is updated (ajax)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to allow fast localDate input (with PrimeFaces datePicker), allowing the input of a date without separators. For example you can enter the date as 31122023 and it displays immediately 31/12/2023 (if the locale is french).

I disable the dialog (showOnFocus="false") but I would like to have it on demand (showIcon="true")

First problem, if I display the icon (showIcon="true"), the tabulation is blocked at the icon and you can't go to the next input field.

Second problem, if you hit the icon, and select a date, the date is not taken into account so the icon is useless.

Third problem, if you enter 7/4/23, you'll get an error. In the original show case, it works.

So to make it work, I don't show the icon (showIcon="false"). But still, it would be nice to have this icon, just in case you don't know the pattern.

So how can I make it work with the icon?

Here is the code taken from PrimeFaces show case "datePickerJava8.xhtml" after modification. If you enter 12312023, it will display 12/31/23.

Facelet :

```
<p:datePicker id="button" value="#{calendarJava8View.date7}" showIcon="true" showOnFocus="false" autocomplete="off" >
  <f:convertDateTime type="localDate" dateStyle="short" />
  <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this" />
</p:datePicker>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<converter>
  <converter-id>javax.faces.DateTime</converter-id>
  <converter-class>org.primefaces.showcase.convert.DateTimeConverter</converter-class> 
</converter>
```

The custom DateTimeConverter. It removes the separators if the user enters 8 digits.

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.convert;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePicker;

public class DateTimeConverter extends org.primefaces.convert.DateTimeConverter {
    //not alpha
    private static final Pattern PAT = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]");
    //only digits
    private static final Pattern PATD = Pattern.compile("\\d{8}");

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, DatePicker datePicker, String value) {
        try {
            String pattern = datePicker.calculatePattern();
            if (PATD.matcher(value).matches()) {
                //only digits : remove separators
                String apattern = PAT.matcher(pattern).replaceAll("");
                //build new patter with MM, yyyy, dd
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                boolean isMonth = true;
                boolean isDay = true;
                boolean isYear = true;
                for (int i = 0, n = apattern.length() ; i < n ; ++i) {
                    char c = apattern.charAt(i);
                    switch (c) {
                        case 'M':
                            if (isMonth) {
                                isMonth = false;
                                b.append("MM");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'd':
                            if (isDay) {
                                isDay = false;
                                b.append("dd");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'y':
                            if (isYear) {
                                isYear = false;
                                b.append("yyyy");
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            //not supported
                            return super.getAsObject(context, datePicker, value);
                    }
                }
                Locale locale = this.getLocale();
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(b.toString(), locale);
                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(value, formatter);
                return date;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return super.getAsObject(context, datePicker, value);
    }
}
```

PS : I use wildfly-25.0.1.Final and primefaces 12.0.0

Comment: Please ask about one issue per question. First issue works for me in the showcase.

Comment: Does-it work with the custom DateTimeConverter and the ajax onblur ?

Comment: I removed the custom converter. It's the the ajax blur event that creates the problems.

Comment: Maybe wrap in a group, update the group and have a `p:focus` in it? And did you try entering an invalid value?

Comment: With the ajax blur event, I can't enter a valid value. Neither by input nor with the button. I tried with h:panelGroup + update the panelGroup. I added p:focus. It doesn't work : can't input a value.